# Saving a workbook

Tags: excel, vba

So I want to save the current notebook in a specified path with a dynamic name based on the date, and my code is as follows

```
Dim today As String

today = Date
today = Replace(today, "/", ".")

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
"D:\CE\PE tracker " & today & ".xlsm"
```

But it returns an error -

> VB projects and XLM sheets cannot be saved in a macro-free workbook.

Comment: You will want to specify the optional `XLFileFormat` option of `xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat

Comment: Try `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` before `SaveAs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stating something should be saved as `.xlsm` isn't enough for excel to recognise the file format correctly. As @braX stated, the file format is an (optional) named argument of the `SaveAs` method. In case this is different from the current file format, this will need to be specified, otherwise Excel will try to save it as the current file format and give the `.xlsm` extension in the filename only, **which more often than not results in a corrupted file**. Complete code:

```
Sub saveas()
Dim today As String

today = Date
today = Replace(today, "/", ".")

ActiveWorkbook.saveas Filename:="D:\CE\PE tracker " & today & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

End Sub
```

Also be careful while using `Application.Displayalerts = False` as @Teamothy suggested. While it has very valid uses, this is not one of them, using it in above code will dismiss the alert without resolving it, and as a result the `SaveAs` action will not complete and your file will not be saved.

Comment: Can you provide an example for valid `Application.Displayalerts = False`usage not caused by lazyness or lack of knowledge?